# Will the weight of vinyl plank flooring cause any issues in my 2nd floor condo?

Tags: structural, renovation, laminate-floor

I recently purchased a condo that is on the 2nd floor and it had very ugly tile.  Instead of pulling I decided that I would float the vinyl planks over the top of the tile.  There was a few minor dips in the tile previous to floating the planks but nothing major.  My question is can the combination of tile, vinyl planks, and furniture be too heavy for the concrete subfloor? Last thing I want is the floor to cave in. Condo was built in the the 90's.

Comment: Nothing's caving in under an extra 1 psf, and 1 psf isn't going to decide for or against long term deflection problems. For residential you've got 30 psf live load capacity in the sleeping rooms and 40 psf live load capacity in the other areas. That's for the furniture, your dance class, and you can steal a bit for extra dead load regardless of whether there's still some extra dead load capacity. Out of curiosity, what's the floor system? A couple inches of topping slab on top of sawn lumber framing and some floor sheathing? Something else?

Comment: @popham,  It is common for these to be constructed with poured concrete floors. The concrete is poured into what is like a huge cookie sheet.  Engineers have figured what it can hold and where it needs to be reinforced.  It kind of surprises me too, but it works.

Comment: @RMDman, for sound isolation, lightweight concrete (about 100 pcf) topping slabs over traditional wood framing are very common in condos. I think you're describing concrete flat slab construction, where I would suspect one of these 50/50 at 3 stories with increasing likelihood for even higher buildings. I didn't want to answer with my 30 psf live load because flat slab columns can support enough square footage to benefit from live load reductions.

Comment: Built in the 90s _where_? Not all construction is created equal.

Answer (score 2):

The vinyl planks are ok over the tile.  The weight is no issue. The lbs/ sq. ft is minimal.

I did the same as you over the tile in my condo, also with a poured concrete floor.  As stated in a comment to your post, the design is such that the load is minimal to the structure.  Otherwise it would be an issue to have a gathering of neighbors in your unit

Comment: Yeah, imagine having a party and putting a bunch of `x` on the floor. As the guests walk in, you tell them, "You stand on this `x`, and you stand on that `x`. Nobody move or the floor will collapse!". Your guests (or, at least, the smart ones) would immediately vacate the building.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but only if I disregard the atrocious building oversight in some parts of the world. I'd want to know more about the structure.

Comment: @isherwood, I hear "condo" and I assume US or possibly Canada, although I suppose expats might also use the term. I too would want more info for an actual answer, but hand wringing over 1 psf should be silly anywhere. If not, then you should get out regardless of the 1 psf.